# C# containers initialized by reference or value?

Tags: c#, reference, containers

I'm experienced with C++, but a little new to C#.

When you add objects to a container, are they passed by reference or by value?

That is,  if I do this:

```
myClass m = new myClass(0);       //Assume the class just holds an int
List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>(1);
myList.Add(m);
myList[0] += 1;
Console.WriteLine(m);
Console.WriteLine(myList[0]);
```

Will the result be:

```
0
1
```

or will it be

```
1
1
```

?

If the former, then how can get I make it do the latter?  My first instinct was to do something like

```
myClass ref mref = m; 
Console.WriteLine(mref);
```

But this doesn't seem to be valid syntax.

Comment: "Will the result be" - not that hard to try yourself!  It's by reference btw...

Comment: Besides you never said, waht your `myClass` is - a reference or a value type

Comment: I'm assuming it's a reference type here

Comment: @Andy: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve....???

Comment: I have an array of monsters for a game I'm programming,  I'm trying to fill a Dictionary with the monsters with health > 0, with integer keys, so that I can display the key value and the current health and allow the user to select one, and then immediately start modifying it.  I want the changes to permeate to the monster in the original array.  There's more roundabout ways of doing this, I know, but I wanted to know if this was possible.

Comment: The monsters are class objects, so they should be reference type if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value is passed by value to the `Add` method; however, if you pass a reference type (a class is always a reference type), then the value itself is a reference. So the question is not so much whether the value is passed by value or by reference, but if the type is a value type or a reference type.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

With this declaration, we get:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(m);

myList[0].Number += 1;
Console.WriteLine(myList[0].Number); // Displays 1
Console.WriteLine(m.Number); // Displays 1

myList[0].Number += 1;
Console.WriteLine(myList[0].Number); // Displays 2
Console.WriteLine(m.Number); // Displays 2
```

Note that this would not work with a `struct`, because the value returned by `myList[0]` would be a copy of the value stored in the list. The `+= 1` would only increment the `Number` property of this temporary copy and thus have no other effect than consuming a few processor cycles. Therefore it is a good advice to create only immutable structs.

---

If you want to display the object directly, override `ToString`

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Number.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, you can write

```
myList[0].Number += 1;
Console.WriteLine(myList[0]);
Console.WriteLine(m);
```

---

You could even make `myList[0] += 1` work with an operator overload. In `MyClass` declare

```
public static MyClass operator +(MyClass m, int i) 
{
    m.Number += i;
    return m;
}
```

But this is a bit weird, unless your class represents a number, but in that case an immutable `struct` would be preferred, as numbers are generally perceived as immutable value types.

```
public static MyStruct operator +(MyStruct m, int i) 
{
    return new MyStruct(m.Number + i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking to understand.  I should phrase things more clearly--whether my example worked wasn't what I was after--your answer was what I was looking for.